# Simple AngularJS directive with attributes is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have created simple directive with a few parameters passed, but my parameters are not passed to Template from Usage code. (they are not displayed on page, no error is displayed too). I also used '@' instead of '=' but there was no real improvement.

I just want to display my attribute parameters in my directive code:).
Thanks for help.

Usage code:

```
<fine-faulty-directive fineCount='111' finePercentage='11' 
faultCount='222' faultPercentage='11'></fine-faulty-directive>
```

Directive code:

```
Application.Directives.directive('fineFaultyDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'src/Dashboard/Views/fine_faulty.html',
        //replace: true,
        scope: {
            fineCount: '=',
            finePercentage: '=',
            fauntCount: '=',
            faultPercentage: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope);

        }
    };
});
```

Simple templateURL:

```
{{faultPercentage}}%  - {{faultCount}}
```

Comment: do you have something in console.log ? does your template is well loaded ? does your directive is well loaded ?

Comment: No errors in FF console.

Comment: In any case you should use the @ instead of the =. That should work fine. Your issue is that you need to define your attributes as fine-count, fine-percentage, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes fineCount, finePercentage, faultCount, faultPercentage are normalized names (such as directive's name), so if you want to set it to the element, each attribute name must be fine-count, fine-percentage, fault-count, fault-percentage...

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Because of

```
<fine-faulty-directive fineCount='111' finePercentage='11' 
faultCount='222' faultPercentage='11'></fine-faulty-directive>
```

AngularJS will translate **finePercentage** to **finepercentage** and **fineCount** to **finecount**

to avoid such circumstances, use **fine-percentage** instead of **finePercentage**
and **fine-count** instead of **fineCount**

NOTE: all attribute which are camel cases in attribute should be separated with - or : so that you can get them camel case in your JS code.

Comment: Your answer is wrong because it translates `finePercentage` to             `fine-percentage ` moreover there is already a correct answer written.

Comment: AR7, BTW it will not translate on  HTML side so on HTML it will be same as finePercentage, it will be translated in JS code i.e attrs of link function.